Error evaluating the area inside an epicycloid, spot my mistake?
Hi! this is my first post on mathstackexchange, so I hope I can navigate successfully, including entering the LaTeX.
And, this will be embarrassing. But never mind, I really want to know what I'm doing wrong mathematically, and I'm hoping someone can point out my error.
Trying to evaluate the area inside an epicycloid: small circle rolling around the outside of a fixed bigger circle, a point $P$ on the circumference of the smaller circle traces this curve.
Somewhat general case: fixed circle radius $R$ centered on the origin $(0,0)$, small rolling circle radius $r$ centered initially at $(R+r,0)$, with $P$ at initial position $(R,0)$. Assume ratio $k=R/r$ is a positive integer. To keep the details to a minimum, consider a particular example. $R=3,\;r=1,\;$ so $k=3$, $P$ starts at $(3,0)$, this epicycloid has three lobes and it is given by
$$x(\theta)=4\cos\theta-\cos(4\theta),\quad y(\theta)=4\sin\theta-\sin(4\theta).$$
The area inside this example can be calculated (as it can for the area of any such simple curve enclosing the origin) as $$A=\dfrac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}(x^2+y^2)\,d\theta.$$ And in this particular case, I am confident that the area should work out to $20\pi$. Everyone says so, - even including my own accurate drawing of this rather nice trefoil (counting the little squares on a large sheet of graph paper). But when I do the calculation, below, I get that the area is $17\pi$? Where is my mistake, where am I missing something?
In this example, substituting for $x$ and $y$ :
$$A=\dfrac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}\left((4\cos\theta - \cos 4\theta)^2 + \left(4\sin\theta - \sin 4\theta\right)^2\right) \,d\theta$$
Expanding and rearranging,
$$A=\dfrac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}\bigl(\;16\cos^2\theta+16\sin^2\theta\;\;+\;\cos^2 4\theta+\sin^2 4\theta\;\; -\; 8(\cos 4\theta\cos\theta + \sin 4\theta\sin\theta )\;\bigr)\,d\theta$$
Simplifying, 
$$A=\dfrac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}\bigl(\;16\;\;+\;1\;\; -\; 8\cos( 4\theta -\theta) \;\bigr)\,d\theta=\dfrac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}(17-8\cos 3\theta)\,d\theta$$
This integrates to
$$A=\dfrac{1}{2}\;\left|\;17\theta-\dfrac{8}{3}\sin 3\theta\;\right|_0^{2\pi}\;= 17\pi.$$
Presumably the mistake is that the "(+1)" in the integrand should somehow be, "(+4)"? But that does not look right.
Please, what is wrong with the above? I suppose the mistake is probably glaringly obvious, but I just can't see it. Grateful in advance for any assistance. Abashedly stumped, Terry

So you should be using Green's Theorem to evaluate the area: $$A = \frac12\int_0^{2\pi} \big({-}y(\theta)x'(\theta)+x(\theta)y'(\theta)\big)d\theta.$$

You wrongly assumed that your $\theta$ would be the polar angle (i.e. to the surface point P of the smaller circle). Instead it is just a parameter (which in fact describes the angle to the center of the smaller circle). The polar angle $\varphi$ here would be given by
$$\tan(\varphi)=\frac{y(\theta)}{x(\theta)}$$
--- rk
Edit:
A better Ansatz here would be
$$A = \int_0^{2\pi}y(\theta)\cdot x'(\theta)\ d\theta$$

Oh, I understand. I can do it now. I had previously worked a few "area in polar coordinates" examples, in all of which the parameter did happen to be the polar angle, and I think that contributed to unwariness in my relying on parameter theta as I did in this exercise. I see that simply thanking is discouraged, I appreciate the reasons given. As this is my first time here, perhaps it may be tolerated just once. Three excellent and very prompt replies, quite unable to choose between them, they're all on the button and I am grateful.

The mistake is subtle. The correct formula for the area enclosed by the epicycloid in polar coordinates is
$$
A=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}\rho^2\,d\phi, \tag{1}
$$
where $\phi$ is the angle between the radius vector $\vec{\rho}=(x,y)$ and the $x$-axis. This angle $\phi$ is not the same as the angle $\theta$ used in the parameterization of the epicycloid; instead, it is given by
$$
\phi=\arctan\!\left(\frac{y}{x}\right). \tag{2}
$$
In terms of $\theta$, Eq. $(1)$ can be rewritten as
$$
A=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}[x^2(\theta)+y^2(\theta)]\frac{d\phi}{d\theta}\,d\theta, \tag{3}
$$
where
$$
\frac{d\phi}{d\theta}=\frac{d}{d\theta}\arctan\!\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)
=\frac{x(\theta)y'(\theta)-x'(\theta)y(\theta)}{x^2(\theta)+y^2(\theta)}. \tag{4}
$$
Therefore,
\begin{align}
A&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}[x(\theta)y'(\theta)-x'(\theta)y(\theta)]\,d\theta \\
&=\underbrace{-\frac{1}{2}x(\theta)y(\theta)|_0^{2\pi}}_{=\,0}+\int_0^{2\pi}x(\theta)y'(\theta)\,d\theta \\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}[4\cos(\theta)-\cos(4\theta)][4\cos(\theta)-4\cos(4\theta)]\,d\theta \\
&=20\pi.\phantom{\int_0^{2\pi}} \tag{5}
\end{align}

I also agree that it's a mistake here to use the area formula for a polar curve as $\theta$ here is not the polar angle (this was already noted out in the other answers). Instead, we can use parametric curve area formula:
$$A=\int_0^{2\pi}(4\cos\theta - \cos 4\theta)(4\sin\theta - \sin 4\theta )'d\theta= \\ 
\int_0^{2\pi}(4\cos\theta -4 \cos 4\theta)(4\cos\theta -4 \cos 4\theta )d\theta = \\
\int_0^{2\pi}(16\cos^2\theta +4 \cos^2 4\theta)d\theta = 20 \pi
$$
